# Finding percentile of a particular input in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset column which contains values. When a new input is given, I want to check this column and finding the percentile of that input value in that column.

I tried with quantile function. But the quantile function gives the values of 25th,50th percentile and so on. But I want the reverse of it. I want the percentile of a given value.

The following is my reproducible example,

```
data <- seq(90,100,length.out=1000)
input <- 97
```

My output should be the percentile of 97 in the data column. Is this possible to do?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may also use a somewhat more statistical version with an empirical cumulative distribution function:

```
ecdf(data)(input)
```

or

```
F <- ecdf(data)
F(input)
```

This approach also allows for vectorization over `input`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to count the fraction of the data that are (is?) less than the input value:

```
mean(input>data)
## [1] 0.7
```

Comment: Or `ecdf(data)(input)`

Comment: @Julius, post as another answer?  (Mine is simpler, but yours is a little better because it can be vectorized over `input` ...)

Comment: Ah, right, did not think about the vectorization part.